# How to return the cell next to the cell that contains a string in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

So say I have a google spreadsheet where:

- A1 contains a string,
- and I have a bunch of cells in Column D that contain strings.
- There is a cell in column D that matches A1. Say it is D5.

My goal then, is to make a function that returns E5.

---

I tried using MATCH, but that returns the number in the array, rather than the cell address. Even if it did return the cell address, I'm not sure how I would use it to find the cell next to it. Optimally, I would like this address to be returned in a way that I can input into another function. So how can I do this?

Please tell me if I can make this question more clear in any way. I'm very tired right now, so it might be worded weirdly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP() is exactly what you need, if you need the cell value of E5.

```
=vlookup(A1, D:E, 2, 0)
```

If you need the cell's address, you are probably thinking about your problem wrong - what is it exactly you want to do with the cell address?

Comment: I suppose I want the value in the address more than the actual address. Not sure why I didn't just say that. Like I said, I was quite tired when I wrote this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions, that will be handy in this case:

- if you want to get value from E5 then use [`offset`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en)
- if you need to get `"E5"` as string, then use [`address`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en) function.

Also if you have an address like `"E5"` you may get the value of `E5` with [`indirect`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) function.